# Nuget Package Manager not accessible if VS2013 and VS2015 installed

Tags: visual-studio

Nuget Package Manager breaks if VS2013 and VS1015 community editions are installed on same Windows 10 machine.

Initially installed VS2015 Community Edition with Nuget Package Manager. All was well, except old Umbraco projects suffered from no intellisense due to MVC4 support in VS2015.

So installed VS2013 to work on old projects.  Installed Nuget Package Manager several times but each time could not see it in the Tools|Nuget Package Manager flyout. There were just two items there instead of three.

Ran up VS2015 and found the same on that now as well!

Is this a known problem or do I need to do something to get it to work on both installations? The Package Managers I'm installing are the appropriate ones for the version of VS.

Comment: I'm not seeing it with the Professional Edition. I've actually got 2010, 2013, and 2015 installed.

Comment: And you see three options in the flyout for Tools|Nuget Package Manager?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's humble pie time.....

If you don't have a solution open you only see two items in the Tools|Nuget Package Manager flyout. If you open a solution, you see three.

Sorry for wasting people's time. Hope it helps other bewildered ones!